# Datastore query with IN operator

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, datastore, gcloud-java

The new flexible environment datastore interface does not seem to support `IN` operation when running a query. I hope that I'm wrong, and if so, how can one use an `IN` operator in the new Java interface of Datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query like - `WHERE color IN('RED', 'BLACK')`, it is not supported by the Datastore (server side). Same is the case with `OR` operator (e.g. `WHERE color='RED' OR color='BLACK'`). Some client APIs have added this functionality by splitting the query into multiple and then merging the results from each query. The new [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java) API does not support this yet. For now, you would have to run multiple queries for each value in the `IN` clause and merge the results.

Comment: Or, where possible, use a batch look-up instead of a query.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the repository query methods, but I got an error informing that it is not supported.

Only solved for me using the `@Query` annotation;

Example:

```
  @Query("select * from UserGroup where name IN @names")
  List<Company> findAllByName(List<String> names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/queries):

> If you want to set more than one filter on a query, you must use `CompositeFilter`, which requires at least two filters.

```
Filter tooShortFilter = new FilterPredicate("height", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, minHeight);
Filter tooTallFilter = new FilterPredicate("height", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, maxHeight);
Filter heightOutOfRangeFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.or(tooShortFilter, tooTallFilter);
Query q = new Query("Person").setFilter(heightOutOfRangeFilter);
```

You can also use `.and()`. The code here is for Java 7. For Java 8 you can find a corresponding code in the documentation referenced above. I hope that helps.

Now to `IN`. While I have not tried it myself recently, the current documentation states that it *can* still be used as an operator. According to it, something like the code below should work:

```
Filter propertyFilter = new FilterPredicate("height", FilterOperator.IN, minHeights);
Query q = new Query("Person").setFilter(propertyFilter);
```

Alternatively, you could use [Google GQL](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference). It will allow you to write SQL-like syntax, in which you can use `in(...)`.

Comment: Does it apply to the new datastore API?

Comment: Well the documentation is still the same so I am guessing yes.

Comment: The documentation  is for the standard environment and not the flexible one :-(